# Problem with understanding of work of np.argpartition

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, sorting

I have problem with execution of np.argpartition
I have nd.array

```
example = np.array([[5,6,7,3,4],[1,2,3,7,5],[6,7,4,2,3],[1,2,3,5,9],[2,3,6,1,2,]])
out: [[5 6 7 3 4]
      [1 2 3 7 5]
      [6 7 4 2 3]
      [1 2 3 5 9]
      [2 3 6 1 2]]
```

I can get indices for sorted array by np.argsort

```
print(np.argsort(example))
out:
     [[3 4 0 1 2]
      [0 1 2 4 3]
      [3 4 2 0 1]
      [0 1 2 3 4]
      [3 0 4 1 2]]
```

I want to use np.argsort to economy some time for executing, because I need only 3 sorted element in each row of this array. I use this code to do it:

```
print(np.argpartition(example, 3, axis=1))
out: [[3 4 0 1 2]
      [1 0 2 4 3]
      [3 4 2 0 1]
      [1 0 2 3 4]
      [3 4 0 1 2]]
```

I expect that the first three indices of each row will match the indices in the sorted array, but this is not the caseю That doesn't work . I don't understand what I did wrong.

Comment: the answer is in the docs for argpartition, so i downvoted your question

Comment: Your example will be clearer if you compare `sort` and `partition`.  "reading" the `arg...` values is difficult, even with `argsort`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`np.argpartition(example, k, axis=1)` does not return sorted array for first k elements. It only returns indices such that only (k+1)th element is sorted. If you see in your output, only the 4th element matches with `argsort()`

If you want first three sorted elements, you have to give a list for k parameter

```
index_array = np.argpartition(example, [0,1,2], axis=1)
print(np.take_along_axis(example,index_array, axis=1)) ##this will give you first 3 sorted elements
```